# Scanning AD for Windows Server with proxy enabled

Tags: powershell, proxy, registry, windows-server

I want to scan AD Computers and get information which one has Windows Server installed and a proxy address set.

How to combine these commands:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "Windows Server*"' -Properties IPv4Address,OperatingSystem,proxyaddresses | FT Name,DNSHostName,IPv4Address,OperatingSystem,proxyaddresses -A
```

and

```
Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' | Select-Object *Proxy*
```

to get this kind of list:

```
Name------DNSHostName----------IPv4Address------OperatingSystem---------proxyaddresses  
Server --- Server.domain.com-----192.168.1.1-------Windows Server 2008 ----192.168.1.100   
Server1--- Server1.domain.com-----192.168.1.2-------Windows Server 2008 ----192.168.1.100   
Server2 --- Server2.domain.com-----192.168.1.3-------Windows Server 2008 ----none
```

Comment: Are you looking for servers with a proxy address set or with ProxyEnable = $true (registry setting)?

Comment: Both of these informations.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a possible solution:

```
$outputList = @()
Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like "Windows Server*"} -Properties IPv4Address,OperatingSystem,proxyaddresses | Select-Object Name,DNSHostName,IPv4Address,OperatingSystem,proxyaddresses | foreach {

    $hashTable = @{}
    $hashTable.add("Name", $_.Name)
    $hashTable.add("DNSHostName", $_.DNSHostName)
    $hashTable.add("IPv4Address", $_.IPv4Address)
    $hashTable.add("OperatingSystem", $_.OperatingSystem)
    $hashTable.add("proxyaddresses", $($_.proxyaddresses -join ", "))

    $itemProperty = Invoke-command -ComputerName $_.DNSHostName -ScriptBlock {
        Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" | Select-Object *proxy*
    }

    $hashTable.add("ProxyEnable", $itemProperty.ProxyEnable)
    $outputList += New-Object PSObject -Property $hashTable
}

$outputList | ft
```